# Python ctypes structure keeps converting its fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ctypes

I have ran the following code:

```
from ctypes import * 

class InnerStructure(Structure):
    pass

InnerStructure._fields_ = [
    ('d', c_ulong),
]

class ComplexStructure(Structure):
    pass

ComplexStructure._fields_ = [
    ('a', InnerStructure * 2),
    ('b', c_ushort * 2 * 2),
    ('c', c_ulong),
]

input_structure = ComplexStructure()

print(type(input_structure.a))
print(type(input_structure.a[0]))
print(type(input_structure.a[0].d))
print(type(input_structure.b))
print(type(input_structure.b[0]))
print(type(input_structure.b[0][0]))
print(type(input_structure.c))
print(type(c_ushort(1)))
print(type(c_long(1)))
```

and what I'd expect is that the type of `input_structure.a[0].d` would be `c_ulong`, but what I obtain looks in the following way:

```
<class 'struct_utils_tests.InnerStructure_Array_2'>
<class 'struct_utils_tests.InnerStructure'>
<type 'long'>
<class 'struct_utils_tests.c_ushort_Array_2_Array_2'>
<class 'struct_utils_tests.c_ushort_Array_2'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'long'>
<class 'ctypes.c_ushort'>
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
```

It is a serious problem, because I cannot force member of any structure to be of type `c_*` and because of that I cannot for instance get the address of structure members (function addressof works only for ctypes types). Is it the expected behaviour or should I write the definition of these structures differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ctypes converts struct fields, array elements, and function results for simple types such as `c_ulong`. To work around this, you can use a subclass of the simple type, e.g. `class c_ulong(ctypes.c_ulong): pass`. ctypes doesn't automatically convert a subclass of a simple type because the subclass may add methods and properties that would be lost.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help. Actually it seems pretty wierd to me that there's no way to have real c_ulong field in structure. This workaround will do for sure, but I'd love to have some more elegant solution.

Comment: The check that implements this behavior is hard coded in the _ctypes extension module. On the whole, I find it more annoying than helpful, but changing it would break existing applications and libraries, so we're stuck with it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks once again.